# Oracle connection in java (error is invalid column name)

Tags: java, oracle, connection

```
    public static void baglanti(){

    OracleDataSource ods;
    //String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

    try {
        ods = new OracleDataSource();
        ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//aaaaaa:2122/XXXXX");
        ods.setUser("aaaa");
        ods.setPassword("aaaa");

        Connection conn=ods.getConnection();
        Statement st=conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM example");

        while (rs.next()) {
            //rs.getString("ID");
            System.out.println("DESC : "+rs.getString("1"));

        }   

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

I have an error my connection java from to oracle.user name ,password are correct but I couldn't connect to db.
Thanks.

Comment: Your query is to select the column `DESCRIPTION` but you try to get the columns `ID`(commented) and `1` from the `ResultSet` which is why you're getting the error I suppose.

Comment: Read Error `StackTrace` which will have column name which is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

The way you use `getString` is wrong.
You can pass an index or the column label:

```
System.out.println("DESC : "+rs.getString(1));
```

or

```
System.out.println("DESC : "+rs.getString("description"));
```

you pass the index as a `String` and that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have a connection error, try below code for connection part:

```
OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
ds.setDriverType("thin");
ds.setServerName("dssw2k01");
ds.setPortNumber(1521);
ds.setDatabaseName("orcl"); // sid
ds.setUser("scott");
ds.setPassword("tiger");
```

If the connection is correct and the query is executed, even then you will have issues parsing the resultset unless you correct the below one as:

```
System.out.println("DESC : "+rs.getString(1));
```

**OR**
`System.out.println("DESC : "+rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"))`;

rs.getString(), rs.getInt() etc all have either

1. The index as an **integer** parameter starting from 1

or

1. The alias name of the resultset output as a **String**